# WPF InitializeComponent doesn't seem to work with DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, timer

I am new to C# and also to WPF, I am trying to understand how **DispatcherTimer** works with GUI (WPF). I want to make my application run a function every 2 seconds but still using the app itself, when I try the following code, the timer starts but I can't use the following Buttons (logout and exit), it's like the app freezes.

```
public MainLoggedWindow()
{   
    Globals.mainLoggedWindow = this;
    InitializeComponent();


    DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();

    dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dtTiker);

    dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    dt.Start();
}

private void exit_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    logout_button_Click(sender, e);
    Environment.Exit(-1);
}

private void logout_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{       
    Globals.LOGGED_IN_USER.logout();
    this.Hide();
    Globals.mainWindow.Show();
}

private int increment = 0;

private void dtTiker(object sender,EventArgs e)
{       
    increment++;
    Time.Content = increment.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DispatcherTimer` runs on the UI thread. It means that when the `DispatcherTimer` invokes its `Tick` method the UI thread becomes busy handling that, and it doesn't have time to handle other UI input like button clicks, so the window freezes.

What you could do is increase the interval time for your `DispatcherTimer` - your question desription says that it's once every two seconds, but your initialisation logic has it every one second: `dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);`

Comment: i still don't understand how to overcome this problem